# Java data access class

Tags: java, oop, jdbc

I'm fairly new to java and at this point in my life, a hobbiest when it comes to programming so this question might be a bit silly but here goes:  I'm trying to decide if a java app I create should be tightly integrated to the database teir or much more losely coupled.

Say for example, i have a database i want to connect to and get some data from then i want to "do somethign" with that data like display it in an app or use it for some other purpose.  Should i do my db conneciton and querying in my "main" method of the class i'm writing or should i instead create a class that works to get the data that returns a resultset that i'll then work with?

I assume the latter but it would also seem to create some complexity which would be a bit of a pain to work with (or at least given what little i know it would be a pain).  For instance in the example below, if i have a problem getting results, i'm relying on the DataAccessor class to log the issue.  Is that how that woudl typically be done or should i pass that back up to the main class by somehow getting the error message artificially into the return value or should i instead pass the error back using "throws" or should i use something entirely different?  Ultimately, i guess i'm thinking i have a dataccessor layer which would do the "selecting" and the "inserting" and the "updating" so that the main class is workign with a disconnected data set and the DataAccessor class handles the details of connecting to, querying, and updating the database.  Is this the best approach?

thanks,
ShermanTheCat

```
 Class TheMainClass{
     main {
         DataAccessor myDA = new DataAccessor("bob", "bobspassord", "127.0.0.1"...);
         Resultset myResults = myDA.getResultSet("select something from somethign");

         //do something here with myresults looping through the resultset
     }
  }


  Class DataAccessor{
     String dbUser;
     String dbPwd;
     String dbServer;
     ...

     public DataAccessor(int dbType, String dbUser, String dbPwd, String dbServer....){
        dbUser=dbUser;
        dbPwd=dbPwd;
        dbServer=dbServer;
        ...
     }

     public ResultSet getResultSet(String queryString){
        ResultSet queryResults = null;
        try{
           logWriter.logMessage("INFO", "SelectString: " + selectString);

           if (dbType==1){
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");  
           } else if (dbType==2) {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
           }

           //create connection
           Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUserName, dbPassword);

           // execute the query to get a result set
           Statement dbQuery = dbConn.createStatement();


           //populate the result set
           queryResults = dbQuery.executeQuery(selectString);

        } catch (Exception e) {
             logWriter.logMessage("DEBUG", "Error creating connection or populating 
                               result set:"     + e);
     }
     return queryResults;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're a hobbyist and coding to learn, or are putting a small tool together to quickly solve a problem, this approach is fine.   If you are doing this professionally or are trying to solve a bigger problem like building a web service, you should:

- Add a business logic layer that has all the details of the specific problem you are trying to solve. E.g. calculate prime numbers, sell houses, provide stock quotes, etc.  This will allow you to more easily test your biz logic which is the most important part of what you're building.
- Add a data access layer to query your data store and hide the specifics of the data store from your business logic layer.  This layer would map database queries into objects, and maybe objects into database updates.  Doing this will let you  more easily change data stores in the future as well as removing the complexities of the data store logic from your biz logic layer.

Answer (score 0):

It's all subjective where you'd want to log the caught errors. Nonetheless, my personal approach would be to declare the `SQLException` (and not the `Exception`) in my signature method `getResultSet` so that I'd have the freedom of manipulating the exception and the log messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think the typical approach would be to throw an exception and let "TheMainClass" to handle it.

If you don't want data base related exception be "known" by "TheMainClass" you catch the DB exception and throw another one more business related.

You also should add a finally statement to close the connection.